# PHP website keeps getting hacked

Tags: php, security

Let me start out by saying I do not know php. I am not a back-end programmer, I only ever do front-end. My fiance runs a minecraft server and I agreed to set his website up for him to help out. He requested for some things to be added in php that ties in with his phpbb forum. I found while researching ways to do this and implimented these into the website and then it was launched. But his website keeps getting hacked.

The first time we were hacked we deleted all of the ftp accounts and just kept one account with one password.
We changed the password for this account
We deleted all files and folders we did not create and over-wrote our files on the server with our local ones

This morning it was hacked a second time and we noticed there was a new ftp account and thousands of files under various folders and subfolders. We asked our host about it and they said it had to be a vulnerability in the php/script. I don't know how to secure it. I don't know where this vulnerability is. I've spent a while searching for ways to secure it and have been reading about php filters but I just don't understand how exactly to implement them?

Here are the only snippets of php code on the site:
This one is basically just connecting to the forum for users:

```
    <?php
    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = '../forums/';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
    // Start session management
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup();
    ?>

    <?php if($user->data['is_registered'])
    {
        //User is already logged in
        echo '<div id="login">Welcome, ' . $user->data['username'] . ' ';
        $l_message_new = ($user->data['user_new_privmsg'] == 1) ? $user->lang['NEW_PM'] : $user->lang['NEW_PMS'];
        $l_privmsgs_text = sprintf($l_message_new, $user->data['user_new_privmsg']);
        echo '<span><a href="' . append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}ucp.$phpEx",         'i=pm&amp;folder=inbox') . '">' . $l_privmsgs_text . '</a></span></div><div         id="loginlayer"></div>';
        }
    else
    {
            echo ' ';
    }
         //user is not logged in  
    ?>
```

Then I have a form that once filled out creates a thread on their forum:

```
    <?php
    /**
    *
    * @package phpBB3
    * @version $Id: twitpost.php,v1.0.0 2010/05/31 2:43 PM PPCW2 Exp $
    * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
    *
    */

    /**
    * @ignore
    */

    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../forums/';
    $phpbb_admin_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../forums/';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/message_parser.' . $phpEx);

    // Start session management
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup('common');


    $tmsg = request_var('tmsg', ''); // getting data from the submitted HTML form (name of the feild should be tmsg)
    $tt = request_var('tt', ''); // getting data from the submitted HTML form (name of the feild should be tt)
    $un = request_var('un', ''); // getting data from the submitted HTML form (name of the feild should be un)
    $username = "$un";
    $message = "[b]Username[/b]: " . $username . "\n" . "[b]Details[/b]: " . $tmsg . "\n";
    $forum = 14; //change to your forum id here

    $time = time();
    $rawsubject = "$tt";
    $my_subject   = utf8_normalize_nfc($rawsubject, '', true);
    $my_text   = utf8_normalize_nfc($message, '', true);

    // variables to hold the parameters for submit_post
    $poll = $uid = $bitfield = $options = '';

    generate_text_for_storage($my_subject, $uid, $bitfield, $options, false, false, false);
    generate_text_for_storage($my_text, $uid, $bitfield, $options, true, true, true);

    $data = array(
           'forum_id'      => $forum,
           'icon_id'      => false,

           'enable_bbcode'      => true,
           'enable_smilies'   => true,
           'enable_urls'      => true,
           'enable_sig'      => true,

           'message'      => $my_text,
           'message_md5'   => md5($my_text),

           'bbcode_bitfield'   => $bitfield,
           'bbcode_uid'      => $uid,

           'post_edit_locked'   => 0,
           'topic_title'      => $my_subject,
           'notify_set'      => false,
           'notify'         => false,
           'post_time'       => 0,
           'forum_name'      => '',
           'enable_indexing'   => true,
    );

    submit_post('post', $my_subject, $user->data['username'], POST_NORMAL, $poll, $data);
    $redirect_url = append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}/viewforum.$phpEx?f=$forum", false, true, $user->session_id);
    meta_refresh(2, $redirect_url); 
    trigger_error('Issue Posted' . '<br /><br />Taking you to the issues forum ' . sprintf('<a href="' . $redirect_url . '">', '</a>'));
    ?>
```

And then the login form:

```
    <?php if($user->data['is_registered'])
    {
        //User is already logged in
        echo '<div id="loginarea" class="bluebox">
        <h1>Log In</h1>You are already logged in!</div>';
        }
    else
    {
            echo '<div id="loginarea" class="bluebox">
        <h1>Log In</h1><form method="POST" action="/forums/ucp.php?mode=login">
            <p><span>Enter your Username:</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>

            <span>Password:</span><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>

    <input type="submit" class="btns donatebtn" value="Submit" name="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../index.php">
    </form></div>';
    }
         //user is not logged in  
    ?>
```

And that's it! Any suggestions? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but I think the best answer we can give you is to get help from a professional. One would have to find out where exactly the server gets compromised, and update all the software that runs on it. That's out of scope for this Q&A site. There's some phpBB specific info here that might help you: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2132867

Comment: Well, all of the software and plugins are up to date, that's why I figured it must be one of these php snippets that is letting the hackers in. Thank you for your input (:

Comment: This is likely a job for a security specialist, but if you want to try, you have to check the logs, check from where and how the hacker connected to your server. There may be an exploit in your website, but there are so much services exploitable, so you have to write down everything about your server: programs/services installed/enabled, plugins/modules installed on your website, check also the versions. Now you can go and search for "exploits". You may try [exploit-db](http://www.exploit-db.com/) which is a real good source of exploits. ---> to be continued

Comment: Check if there is something vulnerable on your server from that site. When you find one vulnerable product, you can search for a patch/update on the product's website. This is a very long and tiring process. If you're unlucky, the server may be hacked with a [0-day exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_attack). ---> to be continued

Comment: If you have phpbb forum, then what you posted is not the only php on the site. The problem/question is too broad to answer here.

Comment: But let's assume it's not. Try to change and set a [difficult password](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/simplest-security-guide-better-password-practices). Try to scan and install a good security product on your PC and your server, maybe the server has a backdoor, and maybe your PC is also compromised with a keylogger. You may also try and take a look at [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/). Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably better asked on Serverfault - there is an excellent reply already over there on how to deal with a compromised server. One of the main recommendations is to rebuild the system and NOT to only try to simply delete accounts and change passwords etc as you don't know how they got in in the first place and changing passwords is unlikely to stop it happening again if it an actual exploit. It is well worth a read:

https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server/218011#218011

Answer (score 1):

If someone is logging into the server and creating an FTP account then why are you even looking at PHP. If they are able to log into the server, the server usernames/passwords must be trivial or there are serious security faults elsewhere!

You need to look at how someone is able to log into the server.

Comment: Well, that's what we thought the first time it happened so we got rid of all of the ftp accounts and only have one username and password that had been changed. We then deleted all files that we ourselves did not create and overwrote all of the files on the server. When we got hacked the second time we talked to our host and they said the vulnerability must be a script in the PHP

Comment: But in your question you said: "Someone logs into the server, creates an ftp account". That was part of the question and was why I created the answer I did. If you are now saying that the information in your question is not correct then please correct it. Otherwise how can we come up with anything like a sensible answer?

Comment: When it was hacked the second time earlier today, that's when we saw there was a new ftp account that we did not create. We brought it up to our host and they just shrugged and said it had to be a php vulnerability. I'll clarify that in the original post

Comment: @BrittanySmith Does your host allow SSH connections? I doubt that PHP accounts can be created via PHP, there might be somebody logging in as an Admin and creating them.

Comment: Yes it does allow SSH connections - is that a possible vulnerability to look into?